# Are these chords in the A-flat major scale?

Tags: chords

I was searching for the chords of a song that I had in mind and I found  a website that says the chords are like this :

C - D - Em - G - D - Am - C

the website also mentioned that the song is in the key of A flat major.

But I was wondering is this correct? 
Are these chords in the A flat major scale?

Comment: Think we need the site address! Certainly they're not. Unless it's guitar stuff with a capo.

Comment: https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/taylor_swift/wildest_dreams_chords_1674166

Comment: But what if I want to play it on piano?

Comment: That’s what I thought: this chords are used if you play them with a capotaster on a guitar. I can read the key is Db. So on piano you have to transpose them all a half tone up. Or in the circle of fifths 5 keys counterclock wise back (respectively 4 keys to get Ab).

Answer (score 1):

Taylor Swift's song Wildest Dreams is in the [key of A♭ major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildest_Dreams_(Taylor_Swift_song)#Writing_and_composition).

I'm not sure where you got those chords from, but I think the actual chords in the original album recording of this song are...

> A♭ Fm E♭ Db

These chords all fit in to the key of A♭. However most of these chords don't really work as ["open" shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_chord#Cowboy_chords) in a standard guitar tuning. With a capo on first fret you can play the following open chord shapes to get the correct chords sounding (as per the recording)...

> G Em D C

This is a very common practice which simplifies chord charts which don't sit under the guitars ["open" shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_chord#Cowboy_chords).

If you want to play on piano you could use either set of chords, but if you want to play/sing along with the recording (or with a group of people playing "as recorded") you'll need to use the original chords.

I can't speak for other instruments or instrumentalists, but guitarists often talk in *shapes* but these *shapes* often don't refer to the sounding chord. I might say...

> In that second bar play it as a **D shape** but **up 2**

...meaning, I want you to play an E chord but on the top 3 strings on frets 4 and 5.

You might want to look in to *transposing chords* and *using a capo* for more info.